# Does adding a * in a style sheet apply the style to IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have been given a old project to update to latest technologies. In the project withing style sheets some styles are prefixed with

```
#calendarDiv{

position:absolute;
width:220px;
*width:215px;
*max-width:210px;
border:1px solid #000066;
padding:1px;
background-color: #FFF;
font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
padding-bottom:20px;
visibility:hidden;

}
```

Now to apply css only for ie i generally used

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <style>
            header
            {
                margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
            }
            #four_columns .img-item figure span.thumb-screen
            {
                display:none;
            }  
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Can any one explain what * does in the above style sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a * in front of a rule targets IE7 specifically.

I used to use it (I no longer support IE7 with my CSS) in places where I needed to make just a slight positioning change (say `top: 8px` in all browsers and `top: 2px` in IE7):

```
#myelement {
 top: 8px;
 *top: 2px;
}
```

So I didn't have to create an entirely different IE7 stylesheet.